# Code snippet for running Stanford CoreNLP Chinese NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm running CoreNLP inside a Java program, using maven dependencies. I need to run NER on raw Chinese text. Could someone please provide a code snippet that will do this?

I found the instruction: "... you will first need to run Stanford Word Segmenter or some other Chinese word segmenter, and then run NER on the output of that!" But I can't figure out how to do that. Do you somehow splice a ChineseSegmenterAnnotator into the English NER pipeline? Do you need ChineseDocumentToSentenceProcessor before that? Can all this be done using StanfordCoreNLP and the right set of properties, or is something else required? I have the Chinese models.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I give up, why did this merit a -1?

Answer (score 4):

You can run the entire pipeline on Chinese text.  The key difference is to use the segment annotator instead of the tokenize annotator.

Here are the properties you use for the whole Chinese pipeline.  You can remove any annotator you don't need.  So in your case you can just stop at ner and remove the properties for parse, mention, and coref.

```
# Pipeline options - lemma is no-op for Chinese but currently needed because coref demands it (bad old requirements system)
annotators = segment, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, mention, coref

# segment
customAnnotatorClass.segment = edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ChineseSegmenterAnnotator

segment.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/ctb.gz
segment.sighanCorporaDict = edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese
segment.serDictionary = edu/stanford/nlp/models/segmenter/chinese/dict-chris6.ser.gz
segment.sighanPostProcessing = true

# sentence split
ssplit.boundaryTokenRegex = [.]|[!?]+|[。]|[！？]+

# pos
pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/chinese-distsim/chinese-distsim.tagger

# ner
ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = false
ner.useSUTime = false

# parse
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/chineseFactored.ser.gz

# coref and mention
coref.sieves = ChineseHeadMatch, ExactStringMatch, PreciseConstructs, StrictHeadMatch1, StrictHeadMatch2, StrictHeadMatch3, StrictHeadMatch4, PronounMatch
coref.input.type = raw
coref.postprocessing = true
coref.calculateFeatureImportance = false
coref.useConstituencyTree = true
coref.useSemantics = false
coref.md.type = RULE
coref.mode = hybrid
coref.path.word2vec =
coref.language = zh
coref.print.md.log = false
coref.defaultPronounAgreement = true
coref.zh.dict = edu/stanford/nlp/models/dcoref/zh-attributes.txt.gz
```

When I get a chance I'll try to write a full demo class for you including the proper imports.  But this is a snippet of code that will run the pipeline on Chinese text.  Make sure you have the Chinese language models jar in your classpath.  You can go [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html) for how to add the Chinese language models jar in Maven.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props = StringUtils.propFileToProperties("StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");
// that properties file will run the entire pipeline
// if you uncomment the following line it will just go up to ner
//props.setProperty("annotators","segment,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Annotation annotation = new Annotation("whatever your Chinese text is");
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
```

Comment: super helpful!! Deeply appreciated